# Чем отличаются потоки от нитей?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вроде как должно быть одно и тоже, так как thread переводят и как "поток", и как "нить". Вроде как, при создании потока (нити) и в послед запуске он может разбиваться на нити?

Это поток порождает себе подобных (потоки такие же как и он) или же он порождает нити (которые видимо являются неполноценными потоками)?

А еще, являются ли потоки чтения (с консоли, файла) и вывода (в файл) такими же потоками?

Почему тогда мы не вызываем у них методы `start` и пр., а только `close`?

Или же можно запустить нить создав лишь объект их типа?

Неужели это все одни и те же потоки? И еще, наличие 2-х нитей c thread и с runnable обусловлено тем, что с 1-ым нельзя наследоваться, но легче запускать, а со 2м можно наследоваться, но сложнее запускать?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Вроде как должно быть одно и тоже , тк thread переводят и так , и так.

Одно и то же. Вот если встретите термин Fiber - там все немного интересней, взаимодействие с ним происходит как с потоком, но классическим ОС-потоком он не является.

> Вроде как , при создании потока(нити) и в послед запуске он может разбиваться на нити?

Разбиваться не может, порождать - может. Порожденные потоки имеют ровно те же возможности.

> А еще , являются ли потоки чтения(с консоли,файла) и вывода(в файл) такими же потоками?

Нет, мы говорим про потоки выполнения, а это - потоки данных, т.е. просто последовательная перекачка байтов из одного места в другое.

> И еще , наличие 2х нитей c thread и с runnable обусловлено тем , что с 1ым нельзя наследоваться , но легче запускать ,а со 2м можно наследоваться , но сложнее запускать?

не берусь судить за архитекторов API, но наследоваться от класса потока вам не стоит вообще никогда. В большинстве случаев вам так вообще потребуется ExecutorService, который возьмет на себя управление потоками, а вы будете просто отдавать ему задачи на выполнение в виде Runnable или аналога.

Answer (score 10):

Трудности перевода. "Потоки" - это threads и streams, хотя в источнике это означает абсолютно разные вещи.

В литературе чаще всего придерживаются перевода "потоки" в обоих случаях (где из контекста понятно, о каких потоках идет речь), но некоторые персоны предпочитают подчеркивать отличие называя treads нитями.

PS Да и streams в той же Java бывают совершенно разными: I/O streams, Stream API.